# using MSMQ with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asmx, msmq

I wanted to implement some sort of real-time alerts similar to a Facebook alert whenever a change has been made using ASP.Net, Web services, Jquery and MSMQ.

Is this the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use long polling.

But here's a comparison of [WebSockets vs Server-Sent Events vs Long-polling](http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling).

It's using php but the principles are explained quite well.